# In F#, How do I use Seq.unfold in the context of a larger pipeline?

Tags: f#, seq.unfold

I have a CSV file with two columns, text and count. The goal is to transform the file from this:

```
some text once,1
some text twice,2
some text thrice,3
```

To this:

```
some text once,1
some text twice,1
some text twice,1
some text thrice,1
some text thrice,1
some text thrice,1
```

repeating each line count times and spreading the count over that many lines.

This seems to me like a good candidate for Seq.unfold, generating the additional lines, as we read the file. I have the following generator function:

```
let expandRows (text:string, number:int32) =
    if number = 0 
    then None
    else
        let element = text                  // "element" will be in the generated sequence
        let nextState = (element, number-1) // threaded state replacing looping 
        Some (element, nextState)
```

FSI yields a the following function signature:

```
val expandRows : text:string * number:int32 -> (string * (string * int32)) option
```

Executing the following in FSI:

```
let expandedRows = Seq.unfold expandRows ("some text thrice", 3)
```

yields the expected:

```
val it : seq<string> = seq ["some text thrice"; "some text thrice"; "some text thrice"]
```

The question is: how do I plug this into the context of a larger ETL pipeline?  For example:

```
File.ReadLines(inFile)                  
    |> Seq.map createTupleWithCount
    |> Seq.unfold expandRows // type mismatch here
    |> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

The error below is on expandRows in the context of the pipeline.

```
Type mismatch. 
Expecting a 'seq<string * int32> -> ('a * seq<string * int32>) option'    
but given a     'string * int32 -> (string * (string * int32)) option' 
The type    'seq<string * int 32>' does not match the type 'string * int32'
```

I was expecting that expandRows was returning seq of string, as in my isolated test.  As that is neither the "Expecting" or the "given", I'm confused. Can someone point me in the right direction?

A gist for the code is here: 
https://gist.github.com/akucheck/e0ff316e516063e6db224ab116501498

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Seq.map` produces a sequence, but `Seq.unfold` does not take a sequence, it takes a single value. So you can't directly pipe the output of `Seq.map` into `Seq.unfold`. You need to do it element by element instead.

But then, for each element your `Seq.unfold` will produce a sequence, so the ultimate result will be a sequence of sequences. You can collect all those "subsequences" in a single sequence with `Seq.collect`:

```
File.ReadLines(inFile) 
    |> Seq.map createTupleWithCount 
    |> Seq.collect (Seq.unfold expandRows)
    |> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

`Seq.collect` takes a function and an input sequence. For every element of the input sequence, the function is supposed to produce another sequence, and `Seq.collect` will concatenate all those sequences in one. You may think of `Seq.collect` as `Seq.map` and `Seq.concat` combined in one function. Also, if you're coming from C#, `Seq.collect` is called `SelectMany` over there.

Comment: Very helpful explanation; exactly what I needed. thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, since you simply want to repeat a value a number of times, there's no reason to use `Seq.unfold`. You can use `Seq.replicate` instead:

```
// 'a * int -> seq<'a>
let expandRows (text, number) = Seq.replicate number text
```

You can use `Seq.collect` to compose it:

```
File.ReadLines(inFile)
|> Seq.map createTupleWithCount
|> Seq.collect expandRows
|> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

---

In fact, the only work performed by this version of `expandRows` is to 'unpack' a tuple and compose its values into curried form.

While F# doesn't come with such a generic function in its core library, you can easily define it (and [other similarly useful functions](https://gist.github.com/ploeh/6d8050e121a5175fabb1d08ef5266cd7)):

```
module Tuple2 =
    let curry f x y = f (x, y)    
    let uncurry f (x, y) = f x y    
    let swap (x, y) = (y, x)
```

This would enable you to compose your pipeline from well-known functional building blocks:

```
File.ReadLines(inFile)
|> Seq.map createTupleWithCount
|> Seq.collect (Tuple2.swap >> Tuple2.uncurry Seq.replicate)
|> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

Comment: I love the idea of simplifying by removing Seq.unfold, but I see no reference to Seq.replicate in the MSDN doc.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: Interesting.  Works in FSI, compiles, fails at runtime on Mono w System.MissingMethodException.  Need to dig into this...

Comment: @akucheck `Seq.replicate` was added in F# 4: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks! I recalled seeing that chart but had not saved a link to it - been looking all over for it. Strange that MSDN does not show this. *It seems* this API is not yet avail in Mono.  Code (obviously) runs fine on Windows.

Comment: Even if `Seq.replicate` is not there, there is still no need for `unfold`. You could just as well do `seq { for _ in 1..number -> text }`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is actually

```
File.ReadLines(inFile)                  
|> Seq.map createTupleWithCount
|> Seq.map (Seq.unfold expandRows) // Map each tuple to a seq<string>
|> Seq.concat // Flatten the seq<seq<string>> to seq<string>
|> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

as it seems that you want to convert each tuple with count in your sequence into a `seq<string>` via `Seq.unfold` and `expandRows`. This is done by mapping.

Afterwards, you want to flatten your `seq<seq<string>>` into a large `seq<string>`, which is down via `Seq.concat`.

Comment: `map >> concat` === `collect`

Comment: Dope. I forgot about collect. Thanks for the reminder!